# Get the name of a class and method as a string

Tags: rascal

To get the name of a project as a string I can use:

```
loc project = |project://Test/|;<br/>
str name = project.authority;
```

Is there something similar available for classes or methods?

I would like to write the contents of a class/method to disk and then use its name as the filename.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, I needed to use;

```
public void testcode( loc project){
M3 model = createM3FromEclipseProject(project);
for (loc l <- classes(model)) {
     println(l.path);
}
```

Sorry, didn't read the docs thoroughly.

Comment: Not reading the docs; That's what SO is for  thanks for answering your own question.